# Submit multiple checkbox to firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using Angularfire and I'd like to save data by multiple checkbox.

HTML

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="addTask(task)">
  <label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="(key, value) in students">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{key}}" value="{{key}}" ng-model="task.student[value.name]">{{value.name}}
  </label>
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
var ref = new Firebase(FURL);
var fbTasks = $firebaseArray(ref.child('tasks'));

$scope.addTask = function(task) {
    fbTasks.$add(task);
  }
```

This was the result

```
student
 --Alison Kay: true
 --Jessica Cook:false
 --John Smith: true
 --Kevin Hunt: true
```

My question is there any way to save them like this?

```
student
--(key)
  --name:Alison Kay
  --checked: true
--(key)
  --name:Jessica Cook
  --checked: false
--(key)
  --name:John Smith
  --checked: true
--(key)
  --name:Kevin Hunt
  --checked: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw together a rough [example PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/IDQDhYJRJzWUKFJ95Wf9?p=preview) to demonstrate *one way* to do this by [extending the AngularFire services](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-extending-the-services).

Note that the documentation states:

> These techniques should only be attempted by advanced Angular users who know their way around the code.

---

### Solution

You can create a factory that extends `$firebaseObject`, and adds a method `.addTask()` which uses `.push()` to generate a new key for a new task.

#### Factories:

```js
app.factory("TaskList",function($rootScope, $q, fbUrl, TaskListFactory){
  return function(studentKey){
    var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/tasks/'+studentKey);
    return new TaskListFactory(ref);
  }
});

app.factory("TaskListFactory",function($firebaseObject, $q, fbUrl, $rootScope){
  return $firebaseObject.$extend({
    addTask: function(name, checked){
      // use push to generate a new key, set `name` and `checked`
      this.$ref().push({name: name, checked: checked}, function(error){
        if(!error){
          console.error(error);
        } else {
          console.log("Pushed new task.");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

#### Controller:

*Note: I used mock objects. I couldn't decode your data structure, and took a best guess approach.*

```js
app.controller('HomeController',function($scope,fbUrl, $firebaseObject, TaskList) {
  // create mock student and task
  $scope.students = {tester: {name: 'tester'} };
  $scope.task = {tester: {name: 'test this'}};
  var taskList = new TaskList('student123');
  // get tasks list for debug:
  var tasksRef = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/tasks');
  $scope.tasks = $firebaseObject(tasksRef);

  $scope.addTask = function(task) {
    console.debug(task);
    taskList.addTask('Tester McGee', task.student['tester']);
  }

});
```

#### Result (`<firebaseUrl>/tasks`):

```json
{
  "$id": "tasks",
  "$priority": null,
  "student123": {
    "-JoMxWoX0tQrGtdP6Qvm": {
      "checked": true,
      "name": "Tester McGee"
    }
  }
}
```

Again, the focus of this is on the factories, and not on the data structure. The form data in my example doesn't make sense.

*Hope that helps.*